# How can I read user input in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

Using Bash, I tried to read input from the user like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function read_from_user {
cat | echo
}

echo 'Do you want to create the folder "new.folder" ?'
var=`read_from_user`
if [[ ${var} == yes ]]; then
mkdir new.folder
fi

echo 'var is: ${var}'
```

But it's not working, `var` is empty, even though the user input is not empty.

How can I read user input from my Bash script?

Comment: Read this [Catching user input](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`read`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Do you want to create the folder "new.folder" ?'
read var
if [[ "$var" == "yes" ]]; then
    mkdir new.folder
fi
echo "var is: $var"
```

If you really want to use `cat`, you could do this, as `cat` without any argument reads from [`stdin`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Do you want to create the folder "new.folder" ?'
var=$(cat)
if [[ "$var" == "yes" ]]; then
    mkdir new.folder
fi
echo "var is: $var"
```

However, you would have to use `CTRL` + `D` to send on `EOF` to your program after typing your input. Otherwise `cat` will wait for more. `read` is a cleaner way to ask a user for input.

Comment: Ok, and you know how can if can I do it by cat?

Comment: @Jor.Mal I added a `cat` alternative to my answer. Please note that it's better to use `read`!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct, you just need to change your function to read user input into a variable call `var`. Also you need to change your code in two place. One in the function and one at the place where you are calling your function. I have modified your code like below:-

```
#!/bin/bash

function read_from_user {
read -r var #here you are reading user input to variable `var`
}

echo 'Do you want to create the folder "new.folder" ?'
#var=`read_from_user`
read_from_user #here you are calling the function to read user input
if [[ ${var} == yes ]]; then
mkdir new.folder
fi

echo "var is: ${var}"
```

Also always compare two string like `if [[ "${var}" == "yes" ]];` but still your above if condition will also work perfectly.

Also best way to do it like below where you don't need a separate echo statement and input will be read at the end out output message:-

```
#!/bin/bash

function read_from_user {
read -p 'Do you want to create the folder "new.folder" ? ' var
}

#echo 'Do you want to create the folder "new.folder" ?'
#var=`read_from_user`
read_from_user
if [[ "${var}" == "yes" ]]; then
mkdir new.folder
fi

echo "var is: ${var}"
```